# Bad String compilation error

Tags: c#, regex, string

What I was trying to do was create a string using variables for certain parts then use a regex to find and replace it. But for some reason that I do not understand I am getting a bad compile constant value. So for the code below `"<span id=\"" + myObj.name+` dos not have any error, but the rest does.

```
foreach (var myObj in listofObj)
{               
  string replacePattern = "<span id=\"" + myObj.name+ "\" class=\"smartfield\" contenteditable=\"false\">\[" + myObj.FullName + "\]";
```

I also tried this

```
string replacePattern = @"<span id="""+  myObj.name+""" class=""smartfield"" contenteditable=""false"">\[" + myObj.FullName + "\]";
```

and, like before, the first part does not have any error but the second part throws the bad compile constant value for the `"\]"`, but this time it says I need a `;` for the double quotes that I am trying to escape.

**EDIT**

The string format that I am looking for example `myObj.name` would equal Bob and `myObj.Fullname` would equal Bob Barker so then ,y regex would match something like this`<span id="Bob" class="smartfield" contenteditable="false">[Bob Barker]`

Comment: What is the type of `myObj.name`? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: `"\]"` is a problem. Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: @stakx `myObj.name` is a string

Comment: @AlexD it does not like `"\]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the `\` before `\[` and `\]`, making it `\\[` and `\\]`:

```
string replacePattern = "<span id=\"" + myObj.name+ "\" class=\"smartfield\" contenteditable=\"false\">\\[" + myObj.FullName + "\\]";
```

This ends up in the human readable `Regex` string (which is correct, since you need to escape `[` and `]` for regex):

```
<span id="name" class="smartfield" contenteditable="false">\[FullName\]
```

Comment: the `\[` is used to escape the `[`. I am not searching for `\`

Comment: Yes, but the \ has a meaning in c#, like you know for `\"`, you have to do the same for \, meaning \\.

Comment: Instead of using \ to escape `[]` like I did with the `"` I have to escapae it first and use the literal? . Trying to wrap my head around this

Comment: @JackThor: Yes, you have to take in consideration the special meaning of `\ `. It says, what comes next is a literal. So `\\ ` is `\ `.